# NSString TO NSDate Conversion

Tags: nsstring, nsdate

I Have a String.

```
     NSString *str=@"January-06-2012";
```

How would I convert the above  NSString like this.

```
    @"2012-01-06 00:00:00 +0000";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter class .. YOu would need two of them .. one to convert your NSString* str to a date using [dateformatter dateFromString] and then another to convert your newly created date object to the differently formatted string using [dateformatter1 stringFromDate]

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html